# Why Folland's Advanced Calculus is so strict about uniform convergence?

Tags: calculus, uniform-convergence

Folland's Advanced Calculus uses uniform convergence to justify the interchange of limits (i.e. to change order of integration and summation). But actually uniform convergence is far powerful than only justifying such an action. For example Fubini's theorem states a sufficient condition to interchange the order of limits and this condition is far weaker than uniform convergence.

Is it pedagocical thing or mentioned stronger theorems need much background than the level of Advanced Calculus? Even integrating (Riemann) the geometric series term by term $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n$$ cannot be justified via uniform convergence since it is not uniformly convergent on $(0,1)$ since the series grows unboundedly near $1$. But Fubini's theorem states that if $f_n(x) \geq 0$ for all $x\in(0,1)$ and for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ then the series can be integrated term by term. Why there are questions like this in Folland. I get a bit frustrated when I cannot justify the actions I conduct, properly.

Comment: When you say "integrated term by term", are you referring to the Riemann or Lebesgue integral?  I don't have Folland's book and I can't tell from the table of contents which one he uses.  Note that the version of Fubini's theorem you cite is not true for the Riemann integral, since an infinite sum of nonnegative Riemann integrable functions may fail to be Riemann integrable, even if the limit is bounded.

Comment: At a lower level, the issue is that for the Riemann integral, we don't have the monotone and dominated convergence theorems available.  To ensure that the limit of a sequence (or series) of Riemann integrable functions is again Riemann integrable, we really do need uniform convergence.  Pointwise convergence, even if monotone or dominated, doesn't suffice.

Comment: Then my whole point is turned out to be just meaningless. I was just wondering if there are some hybrid theorem to justify interchanging of the limits. Thanks a lot, can I ask that how can we justify the integration I mentioned, or can we with the tools of Riemann integration?

Comment: JustDroppedIn gave the answer below: use local uniform convergence. The series converges uniformly on each compact subinterval $[0,a]$ for $a<1$, so you may Riemann integrate term by term on each such interval.  This implies in particular that the integrated series converges to the integral of $1/(1-x)$ at every point of $(0,1)$, and uniformly on each compact subinterval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fubini's theorem is a deep result of measure theory. Folland probably uses uniform convergence in order to stay in sync with the background of the reader. The geometric series does not converge uniformly, but it converges [locally uniformly](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Locally_Uniform_Convergence) (or uniformly over compact subsets, if you prefer).